# Make Sikuli run on a separate virtual screen

Tags: automation, autohotkey, gui, bots

I'm using [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to create scripts that run using screen captures. How could I make a *sikuli* script run in a separate virtual screen in order to be able to use my computer when a script is running?

---

### Notes:

I know that I can simply use a Virtual Machine, but I'm trying to find an alternative way to use a separate virtual screen on the same host machine. This would save my computer resources a lot.

Operating system: Microsoft Windows 8.1

To have more idea, sikuli is like [Automatic Mouse and Keyboard](http://www.robot-soft.com/automatic-mouse-keyboard.html) and [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did It:

1. Ensure your computer has 2 user accounts.
2. Take RDC of your same computer using IP address as 127.0.0.2
3. And login using second account. Multiple RDC login might require some patching. So use google.
4. Run your script in RDC window. Do not minimize this window, resize it to small size and move it out of the way. This is required because when RDC is minimized it blacks out the RDC session.
5. Done.

P.S. You might need to recreate all images in Sikuli Script as RDC has some different color palette.